# Oracle SQL: Get value from column where column name comes from a another table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Say I have `Table1` with columns: `id1, name, column_name`
And a `Table2` with columns: `id2, id1 (fk), col1, col2, col3, ..., colN`

This is just a simplistic example of what I am looking for. In actuality, there are multiple tables in-between these 2 tables.

The values in `Table1` under `column_name` are string values `"col1", "col2", "col3", ..., "colN"`.

Essentially, I want a select statement that will replace the strings `"col1", "col2", ...` with the actual values of column 1, column 2, ... from `Table2`.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with the value you get back? Are you trying to display it or use it later?

Comment: @AlexPoole Display it

Answer (score 1):

If you know the schema and are prepared to hard-code all the possible column names then you can brute-force it with a `case` statement:

```
select case lower(t1.column_name)
    when 'col1' then col1
    when 'col2' then col2
    when 'col3' then col3
    ...
    when 'coln' then coln
  end as result
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id1 = t1.id1
where t1.id1 = 1;
```

If you need it to be more flexible then you'll need to use dynamic SQL. You said you want to display it, and you've tagged the question with SQL Developer, so that could just mean having the output in the SQL Worksheet script output window - which you could do with `dbms_output`:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_id1  number := 1;
  l_column_name table1.column_name%type;
  l_cur_sql varchar2(80);
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
  l_result number;
begin
  select column_name into l_column_name from table1 where id1 = l_id1;
  l_cur_sql := 'select ' || l_column_name || ' from table2 '
    || 'where id1 = :id1';
  open l_cur for l_cur_sql using l_id1;
  loop
    fetch l_cur into l_result;
    exit when l_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
  end loop;
  close l_cur;
end;
/
```

Or you could use the SQL*Plus/SQL Developer bind variable handling to simplify the cursor handling and not rely on `dbms_output`:

```
var cur refcursor;
var id number;
exec :id := 1;

declare
  l_column_name table1.column_name%type;
  l_cur_sql varchar2(80);
begin
  select column_name into l_column_name from table1 where id1 = :id;
  l_cur_sql := 'select ' || l_column_name || ' from table2 '
    || 'where id1 = :id1';
  open :cur for l_cur_sql using :id;
end;
/

print cur
```

They're both doing the same thing really. You get the column name into a local variable from `table1`, and use it to create a dynamic SQL statement to select that column from `table2`. You can simplify it further by creating the dynamic SQL statement directly fro, the `table1` query:

```
declare
  l_cur_sql varchar2(80);
begin
  select 'select ' || column_name || ' from table2 ' || 'where id1 = :id1'
  into l_cur_sql
  from table1
  where id1 = :id;

  open :cur for l_cur_sql using :id;
end;
/
```

But I think it's slightly clearer in two stages.

Answer (score 0):

The select below you will connect tables by primary key on table 1 and foreign key on table 2.
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id1 = table2.id1;

If I got your idea, next step is replace data with data from another table(s).

For this you can make a script.

i integer;

begin

for i in (select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id1 = table2.id1) loop

```
update table1
   set table1.col1 = i.col2
 where id1         = i.id1;
```

end loop;

end;

Of course you have to change this statement for your case.